# C# SSH Connection

Tags: c#, ssh, mono, monodevelop, ssh.net

I'm trying to run SSH commands as part of a C# app. My code is as follows:

```
using System;
using Renci.SshNet;

namespace SSHconsole
{
    class MainClass
    {

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            //Connection information
            string user = "sshuser";
            string pass = "********";
            string host = "127.0.0.1";

            //Set up the SSH connection
            using (var client = new SshClient (host, user, pass))
            {

                //Start the connection
                client.Connect ();
                var output = client.RunCommand ("echo test");
                client.Disconnect();
                Console.WriteLine (output.ToString());
            }

         }
    }
}
```

From what I've read about SSH.NET, this should output the result of the command which I believe should be 'test'. However, when I run the program, the output I get is:

```
Renci.SshNet.SshCommand

Press any key to continue...
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this output (regardless of the command) and any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Jake

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `output.Result` instead of `output.ToString()`.

```
using System;
using Renci.SshNet;

namespace SSHconsole
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            //Connection information
            string user = "sshuser";
            string pass = "********";
            string host = "127.0.0.1";

            //Set up the SSH connection
            using (var client = new SshClient(host, user, pass))
            {
                //Start the connection
                client.Connect();
                var output = client.RunCommand("echo test");
                client.Disconnect();
                Console.WriteLine(output.Result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. I had tried using .Result but was using it incorrectly.

Comment: Mark as answer please :)

Comment: Just done... I was waiting for the required time to count down :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm quite new myself with active participation and all. I wasn't aware of the countdown.